# Sorting On Json Object

Tags: angularjs, json, sorting

My JSON object is as follow:

```
$scope.data = [{
id: "146",
name: "Sachin",
dataList: [{maunalEntityName: "Temperature", quantity: 15},
          {maunalEntityName1: "Air", quantity: 25}] },
          {
id: "147",
name: "Rahul",
dataList: [{maunalEntityName: "Water", quantity: 27},
          {maunalEntityName1: "Temperature", quantity: 14}] }
          {
id: "148",
name: "Sourav",
dataList: [{maunalEntityName: "Air", quantity: 20,
          {maunalEntityName1: "Water", quantity: 8}] }
];
```

I want to sort on the basis of quantity in dataList in angularJS.

Comment: have you tried using orderBy ?

Comment: You can use the filters as well for that.

Comment: Plunker link is as follows: http://plnkr.co/edit/UX7pVhBlQrFK874E86Af?p=preview

Comment: self.records: [{
        "Reg_code": 10001025,
        "Name": "Chandan Kumar Penta",
        "staticColumn": {
            "Check": "Check1", "HHHHH": ""
        }
    },
    {
        "Reg_code": 10001290,
        "Name": "test_B2  ",
        "staticColumn": {
            "Check": "Check2", "HHHHH": ""
        }
    },
    {
        "Reg_code": 10001028,
        "Name": "Ronny Lewis",
        "staticColumn": {
            "Check": "Check3", "HHHHH": ""
        }
    }
] this is my json object . I want to sort on the basis on check. Please help

Answer (score 0):

```js
If you want to sort items in $scope.data based on the sum of all quantity in the dataList array:

$scope.data = $scope.data.sort(function(it1, it2) {

var it1QuantitySum = 0;
var it2QuantitySum = 0;

it1.dataList.forEach(function(data) {
 it1QuantitySum = it1QuantitySum + data.quantity;
}); 

it2.dataList.forEach(function(data) {
 it2QuantitySum = it2QuantitySum + data.quantity;
}); 
return it1QuantitySum < it2QuantitySum;
});
```